# How can I execute a select into outfile query using Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I am trying to execute de following code in Hibernate to create a .csv file from a mySQL database. :

```
String sql = 
"SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'table.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','" +
" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' " +
"FROM match INNER JOIN totala ON match_code= match";
```

The .csv file is created correctly but then I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
at datuak.DatuBasea.sortu_csv_fitxategia(DatuBasea.java:101)
at sortzailea.csv_sortzailea.Csv.Sortu(Csv.java:8)
at html_erauzlea.Nagusia.main(Nagusia.java:34)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:2491)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:825)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
... 9 more
```

I think that the problem is that I am executing a select query that doesn´t return any value, it only creates a .csv file and the method is expecting to return a ResultSet.

So, could someone give some suggestions?

Thanks in advance